# How to fetch values surrounding a number in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume the following sample DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([10,15,9,3,5,6,7,12,9], columns = ['numbers']).sort_values(by = 'numbers')
```

```
print df

   numbers
3       3
4       5
5       6
6       7
2       9
8       9
0      10
7      12
1      15
```

For each value in the **numbers** column, I want to fetch the value along with **4** numbers surrounding it. Such that, whenever possible, I want 2 numbers lesser and 2 numbers greater than the current value. When it is not possible, I want to fetch **k** numbers lesser than the value and **n** numbers greater than the value, such that `k + n = 4`.

Looping through my example, the first value is **3**. There are no numbers lesser than **3**, so the output is 4 numbers greater than **3**:
**3**,5,6,7,9

Desired Output: 
The output column has the desired output, corresponding to each input that is in the numbers column. (I have used quotes to highlight current value)

```
   numbers  Output
3       3     '3' ,5,6,7,9
4       5     3, '5' ,6,7,9
5       6     3,5, '6' ,7,9
6       7     5,6, '7' ,9,9
2       9     6,7, '9' ,9,10
8       9           .
0      10           .
7      12           .
1      15     9,9,10,12, '15'
```

Comment: are the values in `'numbers'` column unique ? if not what's the expected output ?

Comment: They are not unique. Numbers can repeat, as in my above example. Number 9 repeats. It does not affect the output.

Comment: What exactly is the output col? Each row of the output col having a list of numbers?

Comment: The output column is my desired output, corresponding to each input, which is in the numbers column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([10,15,9,3,5,6,7,12,9], columns = ['numbers']).sort_values(by = 'numbers')
```

**Solution**

```
#reset index so it's sorted
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

#build reference index lists
start = [0,1]+[2]*(len(df)-4)+[3,4]
end = start[::-1]

#Extract elements based on the start and end reference index.
df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: sum([df.iloc[x.name-start[x.name]:x.name]['numbers'].tolist(),
                  [x['numbers']],df.iloc[x.name+1:x.name+end[x.name]+1]['numbers'].tolist()],[]), axis=1)

df
Out[610]: 
   index  numbers              output
0      3        3     [3, 5, 6, 7, 9]
1      4        5     [3, 5, 6, 7, 9]
2      5        6     [3, 5, 6, 7, 9]
3      6        7     [5, 6, 7, 9, 9]
4      2        9    [6, 7, 9, 9, 10]
5      8        9   [7, 9, 9, 10, 12]
6      0       10  [9, 9, 10, 12, 15]
7      7       12  [9, 9, 10, 12, 15]
8      1       15  [9, 9, 10, 12, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `pd.rolling()` or `pd.Series.shift()`. Then just make the first and last n a special case:

```
df.loc[[0:4],['n1','n2','n3','n4']] = df['numbers'][:4].values
```

I'd suggest making each new value a column rather than packing it all into a single column as its easier to work with this way. You could concat them to str if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't come up with a clever to do this, but I think this works:

```
df2 =df.copy()
for i in range(-4, 5, 1):
    df2['{}_shifted'.format(str(i))] = df.numbers.shift(i)  #Here I'm making new columns to represent the shifted numbers

df2 =df2.drop('0_shifted', axis =1)  #dropping the 0_shifted column because it's the same as the `numbers` column
```

Next up we have to take care of the special cases which is the first two rows and last two rows

```
nums = []
for i,j,in enumerate( df2.iterrows()):
     if np.isnan((j[1][-2])):
       nums.append(list(j[1])[i+1:i+5])

     elif np.isnan((j[1][2])):

        nums.append((list(j[1])[i-3:i+1]))


     else:

         nums.append(list(j[1])[len(list(j[1]))//2 -1:len(list(j[1]))//2 +3 ])
```

The above code will return a list, `nums` which we will make into a series and concat to the original dataframe

```
close_numbers =pd.Series(nums, index = df.index)


pd.concat((df, close_numbers), axis =1)
```

This should work in general cases as well. It may break in some cases and need slight tweaking. There is probably a more clever way to come up with a better solution; couldn't figure out a clever way.

Let me know if it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to program this out yourself for the learning experience, a really simple way of doing this is by

```
def rollingWindow(x, size=2):
    n = len(x)
    results = []
    for i in range(n):
        temp = (x[i], x[:i][-size:], x[i:][1:(size+1)])
        results.append(temp)
        print(temp) ## only for show
    return results
```

If you were to pass a simple list of numbers 0 to 9, then

```
>>> rollingWindow(range(10))
(0, [], [1, 2])
(1, [0], [2, 3])
(2, [0, 1], [3, 4])
(3, [1, 2], [4, 5])
(4, [2, 3], [5, 6])
(5, [3, 4], [6, 7])
(6, [4, 5], [7, 8])
(7, [5, 6], [8, 9])
(8, [6, 7], [9])
(9, [7, 8], [])
```

As you can see, for the first row, only an empty list is returned since nothing lies before 0. Then, for the next row (`1`), there is return `[0]` since `0` lies before `1`.

Now if you'd like to apply this to your pandas dataframe,  then add `reset_index(drop=True)` to the end of your line to reset the index.

Then

```
df = pd.DataFrame([10,15,9,3,5,6,7,12,9], columns = ['numbers']).sort_values(by = 'numbers').reset_index(drop=True)

df.apply(rollingWindow, axis = 0)
Out[5]:
              numbers
0         (3, [], [5, 6])
1        (5, [3], [6, 7])
2     (6, [3, 5], [7, 9])
3     (7, [5, 6], [9, 9])
4    (9, [6, 7], [9, 10])
5   (9, [7, 9], [10, 12])
6  (10, [9, 9], [12, 15])
7     (12, [9, 10], [15])
8      (15, [10, 12], [])
```

As the output shows, for the first row values `3`, there are no past values so the function returns an empty list, but also return `[5,6]` as those are the future values. Then for the next row, `5`, the function returns `[0]` as the past value, and `[6,7]` as the future values. Then so on.

You can then modify this to fit your purposes. This is just an example of course, by no means is it mean to be "final".